# NSString to NSData using stringWithUTF8String and dataUsingEncoding returns nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdata

When i convert the NSString to NSData and back i get a nil result

```
NSString * test = @"Wft0r3qkzXd5TDBeCahUB3MtHuc8Axwr";

NSData * testData = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString * result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[testData bytes]];
```

Out

```
Printing description of testData:
<57667430 7233716b 7a586435 54444265 43616855 42334d74 48756338 41787772>
Printing description of result:
<nil>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data
                    encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

From the apple doc's here:  [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:)

Comment: isn't it the same as stringWithUTF8String ?

Comment: No, stringWithUTF8String takes const char * as it's input argument (A C Array of UTF8-encoded bytes) : 
`- (instancetype)initWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes` which I don't believe is equivalent to NSData. Is there any reason you want to use `stringWithUTF8String` above the `initWithData:encoding:` method anyway? :) Seems to me like they were designed to work together ;)

Comment: DAMMIT this is so freaking missleading, they should have named it stringWithUTF8CString

Comment: i spend like 3 hours tracking down to this problem, as the behaviour was sometimes expected and sometimes not

Comment: Well, luckily you have stack overflow for all your coding worries! :)

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, you can see the round-trip from string to data to string as follows:

```
let srcString = "Wft0r3qkzXd5TDBeCahUB3MtHuc8Axwr"
let stringAsData = srcString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
let dstString = NSString(data: stringAsData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
dstString // => "Wft0r3qkzXd5TDBeCahUB3MtHuc8Axwr"
```

Basically, you want to use `NSString(data:NSData,encoding:UInt)` not `NSString(UTF8String:UnsafePointer<Int8>)`.

An `NSData` is a Cocoa object that wraps a buffer of bytes. But the method you were using takes an `UnsafePointer<Int8>`, in other words, a raw pointer, which is just a numerical memory address pointing to the start of an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
let string = "aHft0r3qkzjuh5rdsaeCahUB3MtHuc8Axwrfdvxgf"
  let stringData = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let finalString = NSString(data: stringData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!;
```